# Authorization_IdentityNotFound while calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want, when user login he should get list of tenant, from that list, user decide in which tenant he want to redirect

I want to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization API but when I write code to call it , it will returned error, I have get token using below code, it is worked for users API of Graph, but not working for organization api

```
B2BGraphClient.AccessToken = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credential).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I have checked it using Postman, when I have pass token generated using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token this api, organization api returns correct output, but logically it is not possible in code to pass userid and password to api and get token, below is image of postman call
[image]

I want correct way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using Client_credentials flow but in Postman you are using ROPC flow.

The two flows use different permission type. Client_credentials flow uses Application permission while ROPC flow uses Delegated permission.

So for Client_credentials flow, if the app belongs to a work or school (organization) context then for `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token` replace `common` with a tenantId or domain name. If you don't do this, you will get the `Authorization_IdentityNotFound` error.

Specify the **tenant** in the code (modify the sample code based on your needs).

```
this.clientId = clientId;
this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
this.tenant = tenant;

// The AuthenticationContext is ADAL's primary class, in which you indicate the direcotry to use.
this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant);

// The ClientCredential is where you pass in your client_id and client_secret, which are provided to Azure AD in order to receive an access_token using the app's identity.
this.credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
B2BGraphClient.AccessToken = await this.authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", this.credential).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And don't forget to add one of the following **Application permissions** `Organization.Read.All, Directory.Read.All, Organization.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All` in your app registration as per [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

**UPDATE:**

In fact this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization` can't return the tenants which the user is member of.

You have found the correct [Azure rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) to list the tenants.

But this API also doesn't support client_credentials flow.

In another word, you cannot use `authContext.AcquireTokenAsync` to get the token. You should consider [AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenbyauthorizationcodeasync?view=azure-dotnet). And specify the scope as `https://management.azure.com/` instead of `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

Don't forget to add the Azure Rest permission in app registration.

[image]

Comment: but my app is for multitenant, so for that tenant should be common, am I right? so how I can replace tenant common with tenantid?

Comment: @S.Deshmukh If your app is for multitenant and have to use common, using client_credentials flow is not applicable. You should implement sign-in interactively so that it can recognize the tenant automatically based on the signed-in account. Is that what you want?

Comment: @S.Deshmukh Please provide more details about your requirement and which sample you are using.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I need all tenant list in which current user is present, I got one more solution for this i.e. https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01 API

Comment: @S.Deshmukh It's Azure Rest API rather than MS Graph API. If you want to call it , you have to acquire another access token. Are you referring to this sample: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet?   And are you using B2C tenant (because there is `B2BGraphClient` in your code)?

Comment: @S.Deshmukh And do you need user interactive login?

Comment: In our project we have already used B2CGraphClient for user creation  but now I want tenantlist

Comment: I want, when user login he should get list of tenant, from that list user decide in which tenant he want to redirect

Comment: @S.Deshmukh I see. So what you mentioned in your original post is not useful now. You thought you could use [get organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to list the tenants for the signed-in user. But in fact it can't list the tenants for you.

Comment: @S.Deshmukh Please update your post to state what you actually want and so that I can update my answer for your question .

Comment: @S.Deshmukh See the **UPDATE** in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but can you provide how to get authorizationCode ?

Comment: @S.Deshmukh Refer to this sample: https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication.

Comment: We are not using AddOpenIdConnect in start up and if I tried to add it it get error that IServiceCollection does not contain defination for AddOpenIdConnect